# Trac API datetime Error when creating new wiki pages

Tags: python, api, xml-rpc, trac

I'm trying to use XML-RPC for creating new Trac-Wiki pages. My code:

```
from xmlrpc import ServerProxy
proxy=ServerProxy(getPageURL(),context=getSSLContext())
params = {'sum':"Page newly created",'minor': False}
proxy.wiki.putPage("newwikipage","hello wiki!",params)
```

yields the Error message

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: "'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'' while executing 'wiki.putPage()'">
```

What I've tried:

- passing a datetime.datetime object instad of "newwikipage" throws another error ('datetime' object has no attribute 'split')
- `use_builtin_types=True` and changing `params` didn't help
- manually creating wiki-pages works
- all other API functions I tested work, including ticket and component creation (so it's probably not a faulty SSL context)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Which Trac version?

Comment: The plugin is not yet compatible with Trac 1.4: https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/13611

Comment: It's Trac 1.4.2
Is there any way to get around this apart from downgrading Trac?

Comment: You could try this development branch: https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/13611#comment:13 I haven't reviewed the code so I can't say if it will work well.